# Need to create a return type function in Processing that returns whether one position will overlap with another

Tags: arrays, function, processing, distance, return-type

Good evening, I have been having some trouble with return type functions in Processing and I was wondering if someone could explain for example this one to me:

I have an array arrType[3], each index randomly stores an arc shape. I am supposed to draw these in random arrPosX and arrPosY, both of 50 positions/indexes. The assignment asks me to make a return type function to check if the shape overlaps with another, but I'm having a hard time with this as a return type only returns 1 value, or at least I think so? So how can I check both X and Y?

Use a function called intersects for this.
 The function gets the random x and y position,
 and returns whether this will overlap with any of the other shapes already in the array.
 You can assume that they are all circles for this, and check if they are too close based on the size
 Take the stroke of 3 into account to do the overlap check

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't the return type be Boolean (true or false)? Two shapes either overlap or they don't.

Comment: Ohh, so I need to look at it more like a coordinate instead of just an X or Y position. Makes sense!